# powershell get-aduser where manager -eq disabled

Tags: powershell

Im trying to get all AD users where the user in the manager field is disabled

The below does not work, ive tried multiple ways though cannot figure it out

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "XXX" -filter {enabled -eq $true} -Properties * | where {Get-aduser -Filter {distinguishedname -eq $_.manager -and enabled -eq $false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an AD readily available that has populated `Manager` attribute, so the script is not tested. Anyway, a simple way is to create two collections with `Get-ADUser`. Fill one with all the disabled accounts and one with enabled ones. Loop through the enabled accounts and check if manager is found from the disableds.

To make things faster, store the disabled accounts as a hash table with `Group-Object` and use hashtable's `ContainsKey()` method like so,

```
$disabled = Get-ADUser -filter { enabled -ne $true } | group-object `
    -AsHashTable -AsString -Property Name
$users = Get-ADUser -filter  { enabled -eq $true }

foreach($user in $users) {
  if( $disabled.ContainsKey($user.Manager) ) {
    # User's manager is a disabled account
  }
}
```